# Most efficient way of creating a 32 bit bitmask

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I would like to create a mask that sets the bits for the first `n` nybbles,
and the first `m` bits of these nybbles, where `n <=8` and `m <=4`  .

By efficient, I mean a way that minimizes bitwise operations.

Currently I use a brute force approach: first create a nybble mask, then keep left shifting the mask and ORing these numbers together.

Here is my current method:

```
#define NIBBLE   ((unsigned int)0xF >> m))
#define MASK     ((NIBBLE | (NIBBLE << 4) |  (NIBBLE << (8)) | (NIBBLE << (12)) | (NIBBLE << (16)) | (NIBBLE << (20)) | (NIBBLE << (24)) | (NIBBLE << (28)))  >> (n*4) )
```

Comment: Please include some examples and your attempt so far.

Comment: 4 times 8 is only 32. That's a pretty small lookup table.

Comment: Or what about 32 #defines?

Comment: hmmmm, how would I choose from the 32 #defines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
(0x0f0f0f0f ^ (0xf0f0f0f0 >> m)) >> (4*n)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Mask within nibble: 2**n - 1 */
int i;
unsigned int mask = 1;
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) mask *= 2;
mask -= 1;
/* For all nibbles: multiply mask by 16 for each */
unsigned int nibblemask = 0;
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    nibblemask += mask;
    mask *= 16;
}
```

BTW, what's wrong with bitwise operations? They are more efficient. See Falk Hüffner's answer...

Comment: Thanks. Bitwise ops are great; what I meant was to minimize the number of bitwise operators used in the calculation.